# Device Choose Dialog does not show up

Tags: android, device

I have a Samsung Galaxy S i9000 smartphone, and I want to debug my Android app on my device.

I read the instructions at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html. I must say that although I didn't install any other driver than the Kiel Software and the USB drivers coming with the smartphone itself, I can see my device on the list when I write `adb devices` -- I see a device there with some numbers at the beginning and than 'device'. I also see a device in my device manager as Samsung Android Composite ADB Interface under the ADB Interface branch. Also in DDMS tool I see two devices; one emulator, and the other device with the same number as I see in the command line.

I think everything is right so far, but when I press the run button in Eclipse, or the debug button, a Device Chooser dialog does not show up as described in the android development website. Has anyone any idea?

Comment: Check the _Console_ window to see what is going on. The Device Chooser dialog only shows up if it cannot automatically select a target.

Comment: I just change the target selection mode from automatic to manual, than it shows up.. Ohh was so easy, but I think it must be specified in the description page of android. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Check the Console window to see what is going on. The Device Chooser dialog only shows up if it cannot automatically select a target.

Answer (score 0):

Well the steps should be:
- install drivers (or Kies, it's simpler for me since I connect a lot of different devices)
- check if USB Debugging is checked under Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging
- check if the device shows up in the ADB list

If that doesn't work, as was the case with me once trying something on Honeycomb, try simply deleting any emulators and see if it doesn't automatically upload to your device.